# Core data migration error Cocoa error 134130 Can't find model for source store

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, core-data-migration

My app is live on the app store. I made an update with changes to the core data model. I followed the core data light migration on Apple dev website.

- Add a new version of the model in Xcode
- Make changes to the new model version
- Select the option to use the new version for the model (new model version has the green check)
- Add options when add sqlite file to the persistent store

Here is the code:

```
NSString *momdPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PropertiesModel" ofType:@"momd"];
    model = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:momdPath]];

//    model = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];

    psc = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:model];

    NSString *path = [self itemArchivePath];
    NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *options = @{ NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @(YES),
                               NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @(YES),
                               NSSQLitePragmasOption : @{@"journal_mode" : @"DELETE"}};
    if (![psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                           configuration:nil
                                     URL:storeURL
                                 options:options
                                   error:&error]) {
        CLS_LOG(@"store URL: %@ \n options: %@ \n error: %@",storeURL,options,error);
        [NSException raise:@"Open failed" format:@"Reason: %@, Full Error: %@", [error localizedDescription],error];
    }

    // Create the managed object context
    context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:psc];
```

I keep running into this error that it cannot find my original (old version) model. The weird thing is when I tested it during development, it worked. I released to the app store and now it is crashing on all my user's device.

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134130 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134130.)" UserInfo=0x170671dc0 {URL=file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/68165624-8866-4722-8472-F371A1202A83/Documents/DIYLandLord.data, metadata={
    NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 519;
    NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
        Contractor = <6e29455a 13768a19 a9a4a2da 1d8d492e b3cc023d bc06cb0d 298b56e1 b44fba9f>;
        Expense = <847aa2e8 da0a2730 4b0a70a2 2051ed2c 09ece5c4 e1a39c10 a42f0aa2 d5b79ad4>;
        InAppPurchase = <51dc7a31 415ba244 9c175d8f e14f6948 7ebec6a3 463d2995 3ad0b60b 8bd06f7d>;
        Owner = <2eaaaa38 ff6c4d19 6bb2621b 91a2c61a 9f5e564e 4703c68c 880f8ab4 4e1d2408>;
        Payment = <e92d19bd 82637935 88cf8493 e0c73ddc d1ba245e 0d1e49e4 8c6bc876 e9a97372>;
        Property = <456365b5 9f1b3cda 92f663ef 5f8b90a1 4dc5842b 20f58a7c 4521f182 f733e99f>;
        Tenant = <f3a92b85 dace78cb ae9cba8f 73419929 6932ca12 4ff97ebf 8e2d7689 da9c242b>;
        Unit = <922b8c16 930cd7b7 05259da0 79ace226 bd379991 955bfc4a 755a72ef 1e5dac4c>;
    };
    NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
    NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
        ""
    );
    NSStoreType = SQLite;
    NSStoreUUID = "27CE8843-4E80-4F4A-A728-559465D687F8";
    "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
}, reason=Can't find model for source store}
```

I tried to revert back to the code base of the last stable release version in the app store but I also runs into a core data error "the model is not compatible with the store" or something like that.

This is driving me nut. Could someone shed some light on this issue please?

**Edit:**
My app can back up core data files to dropbox. It backs up the sqlite file and -shm and -wal files. If i delete my app and download the current version on the app store, restore the 3 files from dropbox, go to any screen that uses core data, it will crash.

Is there an easy way I can export the data from the sqlite and import it to core data with the new model?

Comment: The error suggests that the old data model doesn't exist in the app bundle anymore. Is it still there?

Comment: Yes it is still there, I even import the old data model from the code base of the last release to the app store and still runs into that problem.

Comment: Did you check in the compiled app bundle? I ask because the error message is really very specific about what the problem is. For some reason it can't find the old model version.

Comment: I do see PropertiesModel.momd folder in the bundle with PropertiesModel.mom, PropertiesModel 2.mom and versionInfo.plist files in it. I think PropertiesModel.mom is the original data model. How can I verify that?

Comment: PropertiesModel.mom is the original data model. Try this... Close Xcode. Open the location of your momd container. Create a copy onto your desktop. Go back into Xcode and delete the momd container. Close Xcode. Make a second copy as backup on your desktop. Change the first copy by deleting the 2nd mom file. Open Xcode and "Add files to..." Selecting the modified momd container. Does that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the correct old data model by checkout a commit way in the past and fix the issue. Thanks all